# How to integrate Magento 2 auto deploy with Bitbucket Pipelines?

Tags: magento2, git, bitbucket

I have some servers which I use SSH to deploy, each time manually, I'd like to implement Bitbucket Pipelines to do an auto deploy.

Comment: Do you use Jenkin?

Comment: No, and I don't want to use it. I want a pure integration with the Bitbucket Pipelines.